# htaccess redirect URI to parent directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite, web-hosting

I have a website hosted in `/var/www/thesite` (apache server), it's a `Symfony2` website so inside this folder I have a `web` folder to which my virtual host is pointing.

So my virtualhost is `www.mysite.com -> /var/www/thesite/web`

In this web folder I have a `.htaccess` to format URL nicely.

Now, I've added an API in `/var/www/thesite/api`, the API is implemented using `Silex`.
I want to redirect all request `http://www.mysite.com/api` to this new framework.

So I've added in `/var/www/thesite/web/.htaccess`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api
RewriteRule ^api(.*)$ ../api/web/index.php [NC,QSA,L]
```

But I get:

> Bad Request
>
> Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.

I'm not sure if I can access parent folder in the `.htaccess`. I don't want to change my virtualhost target directory to avoid security breach.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Why can you not move `api` under `/var/www/thesite/web`?

Comment: @anubhava because `web` is accessible publicly. you don't want your source code accessible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't route a request to *outside* of the site's document root, which is `/var/www/thesite/web`. So you can't access `/var/www/thesite/` or `/var/www/thesite/api` from inside the `/var/www/thesite/web` directory. The 400 Bad request is because of the `../api/` bit of your rule's target.

Something you can try doing is just using php to include/require the api's index.php:

```
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ /index_api.php [L]
```

And in the `index_api.php` you can include or require the "../api/web/index.php" file.