# AngularJS + PHP api

Tags: mod-rewrite

This is my folder structure:

```
myproject/
    api/
        api.php
    public/
        .htaccess
        index.html
        scripts/
            ... all my angular stuff...
```

My .htaccess is like follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^/api/ ../api/api.php

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

So, I want this: accessing `http://localhost` just returns my `index.html`. But Ajax calls within my AngularJs scrips to `/api/something` should be handled by my `api.php` file.

Currently, my Apache virtual host points to `myproject/public`. Accessing to `http://localhost` works fine (it returns the index.html) but my calls to `/api/something` also returns index.html. It seems that `api.php` is never reached. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think you can make it work with the double dots but you are not ending the processing of the rules.

So, after it matches api, it goes on to your last rule and rewrites to index.html

Add the [L] at the end of your api line, like so:

```
RewriteRule ^/api/ ../api/api.php [L]
```

Adding this, since it will probably be needed :), if you want to know what 'something' is in your api.php you could pass the rest or the url (after api) as a parameter

```
RewriteRule    ^api/(.+)$    <whatever_url_work>/api.php?action=$1    [NC,L]
```

Comment: As I suspected, relativity wont work when you hit apache, see this for a possible solution to the ../api : http://stackoverflow.com/a/21324642/3802077

Comment: Cool. I'll try that when arrive at home. Thanks!